# What do these trains carry?

Tags: visual

[image]

The answer is a pair of words.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The answer is:

> GOLD LEAF

The trick is:

> Each train car represents a letter. Each color is a bit. Red = 1, Gray = 2, Black = 4, Blue = 8. When you sum up the colors you get a number, which is the position of the letter in the alphabet. So, [7,15,12,4] = GOLD, and [12,5,1,6] = LEAF

Answer (score 3):

> GOLD LEAF
>  Red = 1
>  Grey = 2
>  Black = 4
>  Blue = 8
>  Add the colors to get the alphabet.

Answer (score 2):

> GOLD LEAF
>
>  Trick is: Each block have different color squares:
>  Blue = 8
>  Grey = 2
>  Red = 1
>  Black = 4